# Role-playing Games Top User Swag

Tags: discussion, status-completed

As a thank you for *being awesome*, if you are on page 1 or page 2 of …

https://rpg.stackexchange.com/users?tab=reputation&filter=all

… we'll be sending you a little care package shortly:

- Role-playing Games t-shirt in your size
- Role-playing Games die-cut, vinyl stickers
- Stack Exchange sharpie
- Stack Exchange pen
- Stack Exchange stickers

You can expect to get an email soon with details on how to confirm and provide your mailing address and size preferences.

### The t-shirt

[image: rpg.stackexchange.com Tshirt]

### The sticker

[image: rpg.stackexchange.com sticker]

Congratulations!

<sub>(for anyone else who wants this swag, but isn't on page 1 or page 2 of the all time top users -- unfortunately we aren't able to gift this swag to everybody, but it will be available for sponsored events as needed)</sub>

Comment: Sweet sticker!!!

Comment: Very nice. I like that you didn't just throw out something with a log on it and call it a day. Congrats to all those page 1 and page 2 folks!

Comment: Awesome, now hope it gets here before I leave for GenCon and I can spread the word :D

Comment: Wow! That's really cool! Thank you!

Comment: Wow.. Had this been here this weekend, I would have worn it to the biggest RPG convention in İstanbul. Still I have our [monthly conventions](http://www.wizardsofistanbul.com) to look forward to.

Comment: Woohooo! What an unexpected and exceedingly spiffy thing :D

Comment: A big thank you for the swag package.

Comment: Happy to hear about this, got the form, but wish you offered a 3XL shirt.  I'll make good use of the rest though!

Comment: I'll be wearing it next time I run a PFS game for sure.

Comment: That. Is. So. Cool. Seriously - I just got the email notice and ran over here to check it out. Can't wait! I too, hope it gets here before I go to GenCon. Maybe I'll see @mirv120 there!

Comment: The only way this could possibly be any more awesome is if it included StackEx dice. That's probably too costly to set up a custom order for, though.

Comment: Extremely cool. I'm so happy for this...

Comment: Wow, thank you. Unexpected and welcome!

Comment: Dang, so close. But it's awesome that you're doing this!

Comment: Now, that's an awesome surprise. Thank you very much! :)

Comment: w00t!  did not expect this today.

Comment: Thank you. Haven't been here for ages, but still managed to be on the first two pages. Didn't even notice we were out of beta, I've been slacking.

Comment: This was an unexpected and pleasant surprise! Thanks very much for the gift~

Comment: Unfortunately I am very new to this site so I am only on page 62 so I do not qualify. This swag is really nice. I for one would love to have one of the shirts (I am a sucker for t-shirts). Are there plans to ever sell the shirts?

Comment: @etank We don't have any plans to sell these now, but we'll make them available for future community events and/or contests.

Comment: @AnnaLear good to know. How / where can I find out more about the community events and contests?

Comment: @etank Keep an eye on this meta site. Any events happening in this community will be planned and announced here. :)

Comment: @AnnaLear thanks for the info.

Comment: ... Crap, I'm on page 3.
That's pretty awesome of you guys.

Comment: Did these ship yet?

Comment: @F.RandallFarmer Not yet. We're getting them printed now that we have an idea of the numbers. But, soon (TM). :)

Comment: I just received my swag today here in Israel. I really appreciate it!

Answer (score 8):

Thank you, a very thoughtful gift/prize. totally unexpected.  Will Wear it at GenCon this Summer.

Comment: We're going to have to be on the lookout for us stack exchange RPGers at gen con this year.

Answer (score 7):

I got my swag in the mail yesterday! I'll be sure to wear the t-shirt on our gaming session this sunday :)

EDIT: I took my swag someplaces:

[image: Machu Picchu]

Answer (score 4):

Just received a certain package in the mail today - thank you once again.

Comment: Awesome! Glad to hear these are successfully reaching people. :)

Comment: Me too, just in time for Gen Con!

Comment: Me too! I'm wearing the shirt today. Also, I like pens. Thanks for the pens.

Comment: I got mine :). I'll be wearing it later this evening

Comment: Ditto for me!  As okeefe said, just in time for GenCon!

Comment: I got mine today, in Korea~

Comment: Same here in İstanbul. Thank you :)

Comment: Me too in UK. thank you! Will be wearing it for the rest of the summer with pride!

Comment: No news round here yet. :-o Guess our post offices work slow.

Comment: @OpaCitiZen did you ever receive your package?

Comment: @Jin: No, unfortunately not yet. Was it registered? (I'm not entirely sure I'm using the proper postal term here but I hope you get what I mean.)

Comment: @OpaCitiZen I have informed our fulfillment team that you haven't received your package. They'll check up on it.

Comment: @Jin: Thank you. :)

Answer (score 0):

At what point should I check in because I have not received the swag yet?

Hmm, guess I'm picking today. :)

Comment: Hey Pat. Looks like there was a problem with your shipping address. Can you email me to confirm it? The email's in my profile. Thanks!

Comment: @AdamLear - I emailed you my address shortly after seeing this note.  Did you receive it or should I send again?

Comment: Derp, I thought I replied to your email. Apparently not. Sorry about that... I put the order in for a swag set for you, so fingers crossed.

Comment: @AdamLear - Thanks!

Comment: @AdamLear - Got it, thanks again!

Comment: Perfect. Enjoy. :)

Answer (score 0):

OMG I just noticed that I received your email but never replied. Is it too late?

Comment: Nah, not too late. Fill out the form and I'll get things sorted out for you on my next swag processing round. :)

Comment: I have the email saying I'm in the top users but nothing to confirm my size etc.

Comment: I sent you an email with the link that should take you to a web form we use to collect address information, etc. Let me know when you've filled it out or if you hit any snags. :)

Comment: I'll sit in front of my mailbox until it comes to me...my precious swag

Comment: I put the request in to have your swag shipped today, so it should be on the way to you shortly. :)

Comment: geekness overload. Thanks!